# What is unit of time average of product of two signals?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, power-spectral-density

Consider the signals $e(t)$ and $h(t)$ with units $\left[\frac{V}{m}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{A}{m}\right]$ and their Fourier transforms $E(\omega)$ and $H(\omega)$ with units $\left[\frac{Vs}{m}\right]$ and $\left[\frac{As}{m}\right]$. The time avaverage P of the product of the two signals (~power spectral density), $e(t)h(t)$, in function of the Fourier transforms $E(\omega)$ and $H(\omega)$ can be written as
\begin{align}
P &= <P'(t)> = \lim\limits_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-T}^{T} e(t)h(t) dt \\
&= \lim\limits_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-T}^{T} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} E(\omega)e^{i\omega t} d\omega  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(\omega')e^{i\omega' t} d\omega' dt \\
&=  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(\omega) H(\omega')\left[ \lim\limits_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{-T}^{T}e^{i(\omega+\omega')t} dt \right] d\omega d\omega'  \\
&=  2 \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(\omega) H(\omega')\delta(\omega'+\omega) d\omega d\omega' \\
&=  2 \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  E(\omega) H(-\omega)d\omega \\
\end{align}

**The question**: the unit of the time average $P$ should be $\left[\frac{VA}{m^2}\right]$ whereas the unit of the final result is $\left[\frac{VA}{m}s\right]$. How can this be and how to interpret it?

**Example**: if you know the Fourier transforms $E(\omega)$ and $H(\omega)$, and you want to calculate the average $P$, then you will use $P=2 \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}  E(\omega) H(-\omega)d\omega$ but this will give another unit as expected?! So, then you have the wrong result?

> What is unit of time average of product of two signals?

It's the product of the units of the signal. In my example is $V \cdot A = W$ which is power and in yours it's  $V/m \cdot A/m = W/m^2$ which is Intensity.

Answer (score 2):

The spectrum of the product and the product of the spectra are completely different things.

Let's look at a simple example. Let's look at a cirucit with a voltage source and single impedance $Z$. For simplicity we will use the complex admittance $Y = 1/Z = Y_m \cdot e^{j \varphi}$ where $Y_m$ is the magnitude and $\varphi$ is the phase of the admittance.

Let's drive this with a voltage $u(t) = u_0 \cdot cos(\omega t)$. The current waveform will then be
$$i(t) = u_0 \cdot Y_m \cdot cos(\omega t + \varphi) $$

The instantaneous power is
$$p(t) = u(t) \cdot i(t) = u_0^2 \cdot Y_m\cdot [cos(\omega t) \cdot cos(\omega t + \varphi)]$$

Using the trig identitiy we get
$$p(t) = u_0^2\cdot Y_m/2 \cdot [cos(\varphi)+cos(2 \cdot \omega \cdot t + \varphi)]$$

The time averaged power would simply be
$$<p(t)> = u_0^2\cdot Y_m/2 \cdot cos(\varphi)$$

The spectrum of the instantaneous power has two frequency compontents: One at $0Hz$ and one at $2 \omega$. The $0Hz$ component is the time averaged power and the actual physical power that would be dissipated in the impedance. It obviously depends on the phase of the impedance. For example for a capacitor or inductor, the dissipated power is 0 and the instantaneous power spectrum ONLY has a reactive componet at $2 \cdot \omega$.

Note that the spectrum of the instantaneous power is a VERY different from the power spectrum of both voltage and the current , i.e. only one component at $\omega$

The assumption that you can get the spectrum of the power my muliplying the spectra of the field quantities is just plain wrong. The math doesn't work out either: multiplication in the time domain is CONVOLUTION in the frequency domain, not multiplication. If you convolve the units work out as well

$$P(\omega ) = \int_{s}^{}U(s) \cdot I(s-\omega)ds$$

which has the correct units of $W/Hz$.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it is very useful! You also mention that I assume that "you can get the spectrum of the power by multiplying the spectra of the field quantities" but I do not see where I assume this...? Or do I implicitly assume it somewhere? Is there a mistake in my mathematical derivation? I want to express the time average intensity in function of the Fourier transforms of the $e$ and $h$ field.

Comment: I do not understand the expression for time averaged power.

Comment: @jomegaA, I use the general definition of the average of a function, $<f(t)>=\lim\limits_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{2T}\int\limits_{-T}^{T} f(t) dt$, and apply it to the function $e(t)h(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your derivation is wrong. Your assumption about the limit

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^Te^{j\omega t}dt\tag{1}$$

is not correct. Clearly, for $\omega\neq 0$ the limit $(1)$ equals zero. For $\omega=0$ you get

$$\lim_{T\to\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T}^Tdt=2\tag{2}$$

So there's no Dirac delta impulse involved here. Note that a Dirac impulse doesn't have a finite value when its argument is zero.

Also note that in the definition of the time average you should either divide by $2T$ or integrate from $-T/2$ to $T/2$.

Furthermore, the limit you use in the definition of the average is applicable to power signals, which don't have a Fourier transform. Yet you assume the existence of the Fourier transforms of the individual signals. So there are other things to worry about than the units.

Comment: The limit only becomes 2 if $\omega+\omega'=0$ and is 0 otherwise. So, this corresponds to the Dirac function $2\delta(\omega'-\omega)$. I do not see the mistake?

Comment: @Frederic: No, the Dirac delta does not equal unity for zero argument.